# reduce running time of java code

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me how to reduce the running time of this program? This is an answer to a problem asked in code vita 2018 and I am getting a time error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{

   public static void main(String []args){
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       long sum = 0;
       int N = sc.nextInt();

       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         final long x = sc.nextLong(); // read input
         String str = Long.toString((long) Math.pow(1 << 1, x));
         str = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 2) : str;
         sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
       }
       System.out.println(sum%100);
   }
}
```

Comment: Running time or time complexity?

Comment: running time @Roope

Comment: What is the purpose of your code?

Comment: Shouldn't `(long) Math.pow(1 << 1, x)` just be `1L << x` ?

Comment: What exactly is a "time error"? Can you share the full error message?

Comment: What was the original problem to be solved?

Comment: the logic inside the loops works and print the sum@khelwood

Comment: And it looks like you're trying to find the last two decimal digits of a number in there, which you can do with `%100`

Comment: i think providing the problem statement would help to answer your question

Comment: @KaranS Yeah, but it's also too slow. Isn't that the point of your question?

Comment: i need to execute the code in less than 500ms @ nico hasse

Comment: Problem Description
```

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

long sum = 0;

int N = sc.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

final long x = sc.nextLong(); // read input

String str = Long.toString((long) Math.pow(1 << 1, x));

str = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 2) : str;

sum += Integer.parseInt(str);

}

System.out.println(sum%100);

```

Comment: Given N number of x’'s, perform logic equivalent of the above Java code and print the output

Constraints
 1<=N<=10^7 0<=x<=10^18

Input Format
 First line contains an integer N 

Second line will contain N numbers delimited by space
Output
 Number that is the output of the given code by taking inputs as specified above


Explanation
Example 1


Input
 4 8 6 7 4
 Output
 64

Example 2

Input

3

1 2 3

Output

14

Comment: yes,main issue is that the code is very slow @  khelwood

Answer (score 0):

```
     final long x = sc.nextLong(); // read input
     String str = Long.toString((long) Math.pow(1 << 1, x));
     str = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 2) : str;
     sum += Integer.parseInt(str);
```

This appears to be

- reading a long from input
- raising 2 to the power of the number in a really weird way
- converting it to a string
- taking the last two digits from the string and parsing them as a number
- adding that to a running sum

Raising 2 to the power of a number can be done just with `<<`.

Taking the last two digits of a number can be done with `%100`. There's no need to convert the number to a string, and then parse a substring of that string.

So those lines can be rewritten as:

```
    final long x = sc.nextLong();
    long n = 1L << x;
    sum += n%100;
```